# Storing React component in a Redux reducer?

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, redux, react-redux

I am creating a common modal React component for my application to display a variety of different things. I would like it to be flexible enough to display both plain HTML and interactive React components.

I've gotten it to work by storing the displayable component in my Redux modal reducer. So far, I haven't run into any problems.

Has anybody taken this approach for any of before? I haven't been able to locate any examples of this online, so I'm unsure if this is bad practice. If so, is there another way you suggest this should be handled?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It may work, but I don't think you really need to do that. You shouldn't save the entire component in the store. Save only plain **state**, which should be serializable, and pass them as props to a component. The `render()` function of a component will take care of the render.

See the faq of redux:

> **Can I put functions, promises, or other non-serializable items in my store state?**
>
> It is highly recommended that you only put plain serializable objects, arrays, and primitives into your store. It's technically possible to insert non-serializable items into the store, but doing so can break the ability to persist and rehydrate the contents of a store, as well as interfere with time-travel debugging.
>
> If you are okay with things like persistence and time-travel debugging potentially not working as intended, then you are totally welcome to put non-serializable items into your Redux store. Ultimately, it's your application, and how you implement it is up to you. As with many other things about Redux, just be sure you understand what tradeoffs are involved.

http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#can-i-put-functions-promises-or-other-non-serializable-items-in-my-store-state

Also you can read the discussion of this thread: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1793

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I figured there must be a better, more "reduxy" way of handling it. As per the discussion thread, storing a static ID in the store and then creating a generic component mapper is the better approach.

Comment: Some components can take nodes as props. Totally legit way to populate reusable components.